# After updating androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout lib to 2.0.2 version got crash isRtl () null reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'boolean androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.isRtl()' 
on a null object reference.
```

[image]

Who faced with simmilar problem? Before update everything worked well.

Comment: Not sure what version you are trying to upgrade from (1.1?), but you can use constraintlayout version 2.0.1 to avoid this problem.

Comment: Man, where you did see here version 1.1,? I have updated 2.0.1 to 2.0.2
of course I have to use 2.0.1 until they will fix the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### **Update**

Google has released a fix in [version 2.0.3](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/10/constraintlayout-203.html).

---

**Outdated:**
Google is aware of the issue. Feel free to star it, as more stars on the issue might help them prioritize it higher. Feel free to also add sample code that is causing the crash to help them reproduce the issue and fix it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170316875

As a temporary workaround, you might be able to add:

```
app:layout_optimizationLevel="none"
```

A better solution might be to downgrade to `2.0.1` until this issue is resolved.

Comment: I stared it already, thanks, I can't add more code , because I am using lot of constrains layouts in my project and have no idea where it comes from.

I noticed they had posted some workaround:

As a temporary workaround you can add app:layout_optimizationLevel="none"

Comment: Yes, best way it's stay on 2.0.1 and wait for new fixed update.

Comment: The last release, 2.0.4 is ok.